# Double clicking on bash script gives me an error but running it from terminal works fine?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

The script simply contains `torsocks ./monero-wallet-cli --daemon-address blablabla.onion:18081` which gives me `execvp: Exec format error`. After realizing that I am in fact stupid I added `#!/bin/sh` to the start which got rid of the error, but upon double clicking nothing still happened. Mind you, the script works perfectly when being run from the terminal, as in `./filename.sh`. It's marked as an executable. Is my system broken? I'm using Ubuntu Impish 21.10 and haven't changed any major settings. Just installed programs for coding and what-not, so it's a pretty clean & new install.

Comment: Double clicking on script opens it in editor. To run it , right click on it and select `Run as a program`

Comment: @pasmanpasmański It doesn't though, nothing open when I double click on it.

Comment: This is the expected behavior. Scripts are run, not double clicked. Not sure what you've expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ability to run scripts by double clicking on them is deprecated. I remember doing this which is why I was so confused about it not working anymore. I guess I was wrong.